# Using wildcards in java classpath

Tags: java, classpath, wildcard

I am running a shell script that is supposed to execute a `main` method:

```
java -classpath /path/to/app/conf/lib/nameJar* com.example.ClassTest
```

In this point I get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:303)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:316)
```

This is because the spring jars are located in another folder. SO I have changed  the script:

```
java -classpath /path/to/app/conf/lib/nameJar*:/path/to/app/lib/spring* com.example.ClassTest
```

But with this script, the com.example.ClassTest can not be found. Any ideas about this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The java classpath wildcard expansion is unusual.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html):

> **Understanding class path wildcards**
>
> Class path entries can contain the basename wildcard character *, which is considered equivalent to
>   specifying a list of all the files in the directory with the extension
>   .jar or .JAR. For example, the class path entry foo/* specifies all
>   JAR files in the directory named foo. A classpath entry consisting
>   simply of * expands to a list of all the jar files in the current
>   directory.

So, what you need to specify is:

```
java -classpath /path/to/app/conf/lib/*:/path/to/app/lib/*
```

If you need only specific jars, you will need to add them individually. The classpath string **does not** accept generic wildcards like `nameJar*`, `*.jar`, `spring*`  etc.

Read [Setting multiple jars in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath) for more information.

Comment: This is very helpful! I was wondering why `name*.jar* didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

seems JVM cant find the Spring related JARS.
Put all required JARS in one location (say c:\libs) and use "java.ext.dirs" when runing "java" command

like :

```
java -Djava.ext.dirs=c:/libs com.example.ClassTest
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `java.ext.dirs` for ordinary jars that belong on the classpath.