# Java compilation error loading classpath

Tags: java, ant, compiler-errors, javac

I m trying to compile my java files . I understand using ant in this case , is the best solution. But my project is a one time deploy and I don't employ it using ant.

Learning the basic would the basic time.

I have a folder name Project and it contains subdirectories

Project
-src contains the source file (.java files)
-bin (destination location to contain the class file)
-lib (contains the external libraries (*.jar) that I m using for my project)

I m using the below command on my console (Through Windows , and not on Linux)

```
javac -cp lib\*.jar -d bin src\com\fgh\www\*.java
```

Still the compiler is not able to find the libraries.

```
Package com.** does not exist
```

Any input on the same would be great. Thanks !!!

Comment: What's the colon ":" doing in front of ":lib\*.jar"?  And off the top of my head, not sure *.jar will work there, but you'll quickly find that out.

Comment: Thanks Marvo , i correct it in the post above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `javac -cp "lib\*" -d bin src\com\fgh\www\*.java`

Also read [Using wildcards in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847850/using-wildcards-in-java-classpath/10847949#10847949)

Comment: I did try that it does not works. Gives me that error that javac <invalid flag> :lib\itext-xtra.jar (tht is the name of my jar file)

Comment: Remove the ':'. Did you give the command exactly as I had written?

Comment: Also can you try adding quotes around lib\\* ?

Comment: i m using java 6 (jdk 1.6)    Compilation error is                       "javac <invalid flag> :lib\itext-xtra.jar;  and on the next line Usage javac <Options> <source file>"  and yes the jar is present