# Java -cp class not found

Tags: java, classpath

```
java -server -Xmx2G -cp config:./* l2p.loginserver.LoginServer

MAC: OK!
WINDOWS: Cannot find class l2p.loginserver.LoginServer
LINUX: Cannot find class l2p.loginserver.LoginServer
```

Aditional info: jar file is called kernel.jar and it's in the same folder where the command is executed

if i use java -server -cp kernel.jar l2p.loginserver.LoginServer the class is started to load but i need config because i have log4j xml there.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10847949/373151)

In java classpath, if you use wildcard *, it only loads the `.jar` files from that location.

```
java -server -Xmx2G -cp config:kernel.jar l2p.loginserver.LoginServer
```

Problem with log4j is that the first log4j.xml in the classpath will be loaded. So put the config in front.

Comment: The .conf files wouldn't be valid classpath entries though, would they? It sounds like it's genuinely the config *directory* which needs to be in the classpath.

Comment: that does not help me, as i said i am loading a jar file  named kernel.jar

Comment: @user1460357 can you try this - create a dummy property file `props` in the config directory with some dummy value "xyz=abc", then load it in your class as `props.load(this.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("props"));
  System.out.println(props.get("xyz"));`. Just to make sure that the problem is with the classpath setting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use globbing like that in a `-cp` argument. They won't be expanded in the right way, colon-separated as you need them. Try

```
java -cp config:kernel.jar l2p.loginserver.LoginServer
```

(With the other arguments you need, of course.)

Note that this is assuming you're on Unix. On Windows you'd need

```
java -cp config;kernel.jar l2p.loginserver.LoginServer
```

(The path separator is `;` on Windows, but `:` on Unix.)

Comment: Not working, could not find or load main class config:kernel.jar

Comment: @user1460357: Are you sure you included the `-cp` part? I'd expect you to get that error if you forgot it...