# teradata jdbc jar not loading in spark

Tags: apache-spark, teradata

I'm trying to load the teradata jar file in spark but can't get it to load. I start spark shell like this:

```
spark-shell --jars ~/*.jar --driver-class-path ~/*.jar
```

in there I have a jar file called `terajdbc4.jar`

when spark shell starts...I do this

```
scala> sc.addJar("terajdbc4.jar")
15/12/07 12:27:55 INFO SparkContext: Added JAR terajdbc4.jar at http://1.2.4.4:41601/jars/terajdbc4.jar with timestamp 1449509275187

scala> sc.jars
res1: Seq[String] = List(file:/home/user1/spark-cassandra-connector_2.10-1.0.0-beta1.jar)

scala>
```

but its not there in the jars. why is it missing still?

EDIT:

ok. I got the jar to load, but I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
```

I do the following:

```
scala> sc.jars
res4: Seq[String] = List(file:/home/user/terajdbc4.jar)

scala> import com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
import com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver

scala> Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver")
res5: Class[_] = class com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
```

and then this:

```
val jdbcDF = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
  "url" -> "jdbc:teradata://dbinstn, TMODE=TERA, user=user1, password=pass1",
  "dbtable" -> "db1a.table1a",
  "driver" -> "com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"))
```

and then I get this:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spark-shell --jars ~/*.jar --driver-class-path ~/*.jar
```

please refer to [Using wildcards in java classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10847850/using-wildcards-in-java-classpath)
The wildcards like ***.jar** is not supported, please try to add specific jar file path.